# command line curl - file naming example.com/[1-10].txt => 01.txt through 10.txt

Tags: curl

Is it possible to set the variable portion of the file name output to be a specific length and fill the extra spaces with zeros.

I want things to be ordered for other users, so I would like

```
curl http://example.com/[1-12]/file_name[1-50].kmz -o file_name-#1-#2.kmz'
```

to look like

> file_name-01-01.kmz **or** file_name-12-50.kmz

rather than

> file_name-1-1.kmz **and** file_name-12-50.kmz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pad the format with leading zeros. So for your example do:

```
curl http://example.com/[01-12]/file_name[01-50].kmz -o file_name-#1-#2.kmz'
```

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? Padding with zeros will fetch an incorrect URL. Also, a quote is missing from this string.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. You could use [Bash brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) in a clever way to generate zero-padded filenames, but it will soon become complex. Easier is to batch rename after you have downloaded the files, using e.g. the `prename` script, which is available in at least Debian based distributions after installation of Perl.

This `prename` command will do zero padding to three digits (change the {3} to another number to change the zero padding. Make sure there are >{n-1} zeros after the second slash in the first expression):

```
$ ls
file_name-1-1.kmz  file_name-12-112.kmz  file_name-12-50.kmz  file_name-140-88.kmz
$ prename -v 's/([0-9]+)/00$1/g; s/0+([0-9]{3})/$1/g' *
file_name-1-1.kmz renamed as file_name-001-001.kmz
file_name-12-112.kmz renamed as file_name-012-112.kmz
file_name-12-50.kmz renamed as file_name-012-050.kmz
file_name-140-88.kmz renamed as file_name-140-088.kmz
```

Run as `prename -n`the first time to be able to visually inspect the renames without doing any changes. Check `man prename`.

The rename expression works by first padding all numbers with n-1 zeros, then removing as many zeroes as is needed to have n digits left in all numbers. It will not truncate information, which is nice.

Float numbers are not handled above (e.g. `file_name-12.7-112.97.kmz`), but can be easily done with

```
s/([^\.0-9])([0-9]+)/${1}00$2/g; s/0+([0-9]{3})/$1/g
```

but that more general version is also more indecipherable :-) (and might have its own share of bugs; if floats are not needed, use the earlier version).

(`prename` is actually linked as `rename` on most systems.)